# Calling multiple APIs without too much nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I need to call multiple endpoints with each call dependent on the results of the previous call.

```
return http.get('url1')
  .then(response1 => {
     return response1.data
  })
  .then(data => {
    http.get('url2' + data) 
      .then(response2 => {
        return response2.data 
      }) // etc ... until the 'nth url'
  })
```

It can get quite nested. Is there a way to flatten this, maybe using generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are made for flattening:

```
return http.get('url1').then(response1 => {
     return response1.data
  }).then(data => {
     return http.get('url2' + data);
  }).then(response2 => {
     return http.get('url3' + response2.data);
  }) // ...etc
```

If your JavaScript engine supports `async`/`await`, this can be made shorter and more readable within an `async` function:

```
async function demo() {
    const response1 = await http.get('url1');
    const response2 = await http.get('url2' + response1.data);
    const response3 = await http.get('url3' + response2.data);
    // ...
    return responseN;
}
```

... and then call that:

```
demo().then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // ...etc
});
```

Comment: If your environment/setup supports it, you can flatten this code even further using the async/await syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's a great solution to avoid the string of `then()`, but ou don't need to nest:

```
return http.get('url1')
.then(response1 => response1.data)
.then(data => http.get('url2' + data))
.then(response2 => response2.data ) 
// etc ... until the 'nth url'
```

If the pattern is the same in every case, you may be able to pass a list of urls and use `reduce()`

Answer (score 0):

Flatten promise-chains by returning whenever you have a new promise. However, when you have a non-promise value, don't. It just wastes of a micro-task. Just use the value directly instead:

```
return http.get('url1')
  .then(response => http.get('url2' + response.data)) 
  .then(response => doSomethingWith(response.data))
```

To get a simple `data` variable name, use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) instead:

```
return http.get('url1')
  .then(({data}) => http.get('url2' + data)) 
  .then(({data}) => doSomethingWith(data))
```